# how to create array with key name same as $variable name assigning to array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am assigning an array with the $variables(have different name) that have some values like:

```
array($one, $two, $three);
```

now i am a searching a way that is there any way to assign this above array with key name same as variable name directly, finally i want to make this array like:

```
array(
      "one" => $one, 
      "two" => $two, 
      "three" => $three
)
```

if this can possible at the time of assigning array with the variable then i would be good for me then i can easily extract() this array and i don't have to do operation to open this array and assigning these values with the $variable name, if any function() exist for that then it will be good, please help if any one knows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`compact` is the inverse of `extract`. Use it like this :

```
$array = compact ('one', 'two', 'three');
```

This will look for the variables named 'one', 'two', 'three', and does exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: This is what i am searching for thanks @Lorenz Meyer

Answer (score 0):

Here is a limitation you have add 2 times `get_defined_vars();`

[**PHP code demo**](https://eval.in/776504)

```
<?php

$someVariable=1;
$someVariable=2;
$someVariable=3;
$definedOld=get_defined_vars();//this will bring all variables defined till now.

$one="test1";
$two="test2";
$three="test3";

$definedNew = get_defined_vars();//this will bring all variables defined till now.

$variables=array_diff($definedNew,$definedOld);//finding the difference
print_r($variables);
```

Comment: i know this can be done by some logics but i am searching for a function